# 3-adic valuation of a sum involving binomial coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, p-adic

Let $$a(n) = \sum_{0 \leq k \leq n} {n \choose k}{{n+k} \choose k},$$ and define
$b(n) = \nu_3 \bigl(a(n)\bigr)$, where $\nu_3$ is the $3$-adic valuation.  About twenty years ago or so, I discovered (empirically) the following conjectured expression for $b(n)$:

$$b(n) = \begin{cases}
        b\bigl(\lfloor n/3 \rfloor\bigr) + \bigl(\lfloor n/3 \rfloor \bmod 2\bigr), & \text{if
        $n \equiv 0,2$ (mod 3); } \\
        b\bigl(\lfloor n/9 \rfloor\bigr) + 1, & \text{if $n \equiv 1$ (mod 3).}
        \end{cases} \tag{$*$}$$

But I have not been able to prove it.

For some background, the problem has some similarity to the following theorem, a weaker version of which was originally suggested by N. Strauss:
$$\text{If}\quad r(n) = \sum_{0 \leq i < n} {{2i} \choose i},\quad\text{then}\quad \nu_3 \bigl(r(n)\bigr) = \nu_3\left ( n^2 {{2n} \choose n}\right),$$ which I proved by a kind of tedious argument, with Jean-Paul Allouche.  Later, another more elegant proof was given by Don Zagier. See [here](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/amm/99/fulltext.pdf).

Can anybody prove $(*)$?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Really?  It's not obvious?  I am asking for a proof (or counterexample, if it's false).

Comment: It was my guess after 30s rereading to find where is the question, but it's better now that it's explicit. Also I wasn't 100% sure that "a more elegant proof by Zagier" does not refer to your conjecture.

Comment: It's worth to mention that the $a(n)$ form https://oeis.org/A001850 with tons of useful info and references. E.g., *"$a(n)=P_n(3)$, where $P_n$ is $n$-th Legendre polynomial"* sounds particularly relevant.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there anything special about $3?$ Do you have results for any other prime (even or otherwise)?

Comment: I have no results for anything other than 3.  Maybe that is because of Alekseyev's observation?  I don't know.

Comment: Perhaps the right generalization is that the sequence $f(n) =  \nu_p(P_n (p))$, for $P_n$ the $n$'th Legendre polynomial, and $p$ is a prime $\geq 3$, is a $p$-regular sequence (in the sense of my paper with Allouche).  I just tried it for $p = 5$ and it seems to satisfy relations like $f(5n+2) = f(5n)$, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The $3$-adic evaluation you seek is compactly given by
$$\nu_3(a_{2n})=\nu_3\left(\binom{2n}n\right) \qquad \text{and} \qquad
\nu_3(a_{2n+1})=\nu_3\left(3(2n+1)\binom{2n}n\right),$$
which can be proved inductively using the well-known recurrence
$$na_n=3(2n-1)a_{n-1}-(n-1)a_{n-2}$$
according to the parity of $n$. To address Cigler's request, here is an illustration for the case even: $(2n)a_{2n}=3(4n-1)a_{2n-1}-(2n-1)a_{2n-2}$ and by induction assumption 
$$\nu_3(3(4n-1)a_{2n-1})=\nu_3\left(9(4n-1)(2n-1)\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\right) \qquad\text{and}\qquad \nu_3((2n-1)a_{2n-2})=\nu_3\left((2n-1)\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\right).$$ 
So, $\nu_3(3(4n-1)a_{2n-1})>\nu_3((2n-1)a_{2n-2})$ and 
$\nu_3((2n)a_{2n})=\nu_3((2n-1)\binom{2n-2}{n-1})$; or,
\begin{align}
\nu_3(a_{2n})&=\nu_3\left(\frac{(2n-1)}{2n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\right)
=\nu_3\left(\frac14\binom{2n}n\right)=\nu_3\left(\binom{2n}n\right)
\end{align}
as desired.

Comment: Right!  And then the generalization to odd $p$ (mentioned below) is $\nu_p (f(2n)) = \nu_p ({{2n} \choose n})$ and $\nu_p (f(2n+1)) = \nu_p(p(2n+1){{2n} \choose n})$.   Very nice.  Thanks so much.

Comment: And for $p = 2$ it is $\nu_2(L_n (2)) = (n \bmod 2)-\nu_2 (n!)$.

Comment: @Amdeberhan: Could you please mention the details of your proof?

Comment: @Amdeberhan: Thank you for the details. But I still have difficulties  if $n=6m+3$.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, the observation by Max Alexseyev seems to provide the idea I need!

The conjecture I made above can be generalized as follows:

Let p > 2 be a prime, and let $L_n (x)$ be the Legendre polynomial.  Define
$f(n) = \nu_p (L_n (p))$ for $n \geq 0$.  Then
for $n \geq 0$ and $0 \leq a < p$ we have 
$f(pn+a) = \begin{cases}
f(n) +  (n \bmod 2), & \text{if $a$ even}; \\
f(n) + 1 - (n \bmod 2), & \text{if $a$ odd}.
\end{cases}$

I will now try to prove this more general statement, which I suspect will actually be easier.  It probably follows from Bonnet's recursion formula for the Legendre polynomials $(n+1)P_{n+1}(x)=(2n+1)xP_{n}(x)-nP_{n-1}(x)$.