# $p$-adic valuation of $P_n(p)$ if $P_n$ is the $n$th Legendre polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, p-adic

In [3-adic valuation of a sum involving binomial coefficients](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269052/3-adic-valuation-of-a-sum-involving-binomial-coefficients)  the $p$-adic valuation of $P_n(p)$ has been obtained.
Computations indicate that  $M_n(p)=\sum\binom{n}{k}^2(p-1)^k$ for odd $p$ has the same $p$-adic valuation:
$$\nu_p (P_n(p)) = \nu_p (M_n(p)).$$

Is this true for all odd $p$?

(Note that $P_n(3)=M  _n(3)$).

Comment: I am surprised that this has attracted a vote to close. Would whoever did so like to explain why?

Comment: This surprises me as well. Moderators should intervene often because I've seen such "unjustified" closes happening quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggestion, in case it helps.

The two sequences satisfy the following recurrences, respectively,
\begin{align}
nP_n(p)&=p(2n-1)P_{n-1}(p)-(n-1)P_{n-2}(p) \\
nM_n(p)&=p(2n-1)M_{n-1}(p)-(n-1)M_{n-2}(p)\cdot(p-2)^2.
\end{align}

Comment: With the method you gave for $p=3$ it is easy to obtain $\nu_p(M_{2n}(p))=\nu_p(P_{2n}(p))=\nu_p(\binom{2n}{n}).$ But for most odd $n$ the valuations of the terms of the right-hand side are equal.